# Angular UI grid cell templates form element deselected after scroll

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dO0lBFdiSIXSjz1DPcCX?p=preview)

Am uisng angular UI grid celltemplate option in columndef, within the celltemplate am haivng some elements(select, radio or checkboxes). Now i check the form element and scroll the grid to left and again to right the selection of element is deselected. This happens only on horizontal scrolling.

```
{ name:'radio',field:'radio', width:150, cellTemplate: '<div><input name="Release{{select=grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)}}" ng-model="releaseAction" type="radio" ng-value="0" style="width:20px;"> </div>' },
```

Check my plunker example
[image: While Select]
[image: After Select]

Comment: Did you manage to fix this in the end?

Comment: almost similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206395/celltemplate-in-angular-ui-grid-is-not-working-properly     and seem to have no lead

Answer (score 0):

Its old, but putting a solution just in case someone needs it.
The radio `ng-model` should be updated to contain `row.entity` as

```
<div>
   <input 
       name="Release{{select=grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)}}" 
       ng-model="row.entity.releaseAction" 
       type="radio" 
       ng-value="0" 
       style="width:20px;"> 
</div>
```