# Celltemplate in angular-ui-grid is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using [UI-Grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid) to show data of attendance in my angular app.I have used i have three options for attendance stored in separate array.

```
$scope.gridOptions.data.attendance=[{'persent'},{'absent'},{'leave'}];
```

and number of students are shown as:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data=students;//from ajax request
```

Now i want to show dropdown in attendance column as.

[image]

I also want to show the persent as default selected option.so i used ng-options in celltemplate and code is like:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
           {
                name: "stdattendance",
                displayName: "Attendance",
                width: '20%',
                cellClass: 'grid-align',
                cellTemplate:'<select ng-model="row.entity.stdattendnce" ng-init="row.entity.stdattendnce=row.entity.attendance[0]"
                ng-options="s as s.description for s in row.entity.attendance track by s.id"></select>'
               }]
```

The problems i am facing are:

1-the default options persent is selected in the grid shown without scrolling while in lower part of grid it is not selected.

2-When i am selecting an option it is also selected in some of lower grid randomly.

I can't figure out this strange behavior.will anyone help here???

Answer (score 0):

ng-init="row.entity.stdattendnce=row.entity.attendance[0] 
Is the typo causing a problem? 
It would help to see this in a plunkr. 
This is the angular plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/RJZXudKJKBVIKhoxjXW0

```
<body ng-app="defaultValueSelect"> 
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController"> 
  <form name="myForm"> 
    <label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label> 
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" 
      ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" 
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select> 
  </form> 
  <hr> 
  <tt>option = {{data.selectedOption}}</tt><br/> 
</div> 
</body>
```

Notice that the selected option is set in the scope and identified in the template using ng-model.

Comment: my question is i have problem in using this in grid.